# Can not render SwiftUI preview from Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swiftui

I have a `SwiftUI` struct in a common library that I ship to myself.

```swift
public struct NTextField: View {
    public var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }

    public init() {

    }
}

struct NTextField_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NTextField()
    }
}
```

I click on the file and the WYSIWYG preview fails to load

[image]

When clicking 'Diagnostics' I see something like this:

```sh
Error Domain=com.apple.dt.UITestingAgent Code=-1 "failed to load library at path "/Users/<my_app_name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<my_app_name>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/<my_app_name>/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<my_custom_pod>/<my_custom_pod>.framework/<my_custom_pod>": Library not loaded:
```

Any ideas? I deleted derived data, cleaned and built.

Also found [this on the cocoapods git hub issue tracker](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9275).

Answer (score 14):

You could try adding this in your Podfile (as suggested by [JamesHurst](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9275#issuecomment-576766934), [cltnschlosser](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9275#issuecomment-566305829) and [andersio](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9275#issuecomment-566688535))

```
class Pod::Target::BuildSettings::AggregateTargetSettings
    alias_method :ld_runpath_search_paths_original, :ld_runpath_search_paths

    def ld_runpath_search_paths
        return ld_runpath_search_paths_original unless configuration_name == "Debug"
        return ld_runpath_search_paths_original + framework_search_paths
    end
end

class Pod::Target::BuildSettings::PodTargetSettings
    alias_method :ld_runpath_search_paths_original, :ld_runpath_search_paths

    def ld_runpath_search_paths
        return (ld_runpath_search_paths_original || []) + framework_search_paths
    end
end
```

Comment: This does not compile ruby 2.6.0 cocoapods 1.9.3
```
NoMethodError - undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: ```return (ld_runpath_search_paths_original || []) + framework_search_paths``` in class Pod::Target::BuildSettings::AggregateTargetSettings fix that :)